# onselect work from the second time only

Tags: javascript, html

I have below code working as desired but the on select works only from the second select change.

Any idea how to fix that?

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/3dCyw/)

```
<html>
<head>

<title>select & select</title>


<script type='text/javascript'>

var select2data = {

  'English': [['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3]],
  'Spanish': [['Uno', 1], ['Dos', 2], ['Tres', 3]]
};


function change_second_select(){
var sel1 = document.getElementById('select1')
  , sel2 = document.getElementById('select2');
sel1.onchange = function() {
  var os = select2data[sel1.value]; // Get the options required by select1.
  if (os) {
    sel2.options.length = 0; // Clear the options for select2.
    for (var i=0; i<os.length; i++) {
      var o = new Option(os[i][0], os[i][1]);
      try { // Add each option, allowing for browser differences.
        sel2.add(o);
      } catch (ex) {
        sel2.add(o, null);
      }
    }
    sel2.selectedIndex = 0;

  }
  return true;
};
}


</script>


<select id="select1" onchange="change_second_select();">
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">

</select>


</head>
    </html>
```

Comment: if somebody wonders what this question was about ... kind of double definition of the function. remove `sel1.onchange = function() {
` and one `}` and .... that's it . Thank you @Cybernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your change_on_select to as below:

Working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/3dCyw/1/

```
function change_second_select(){
var sel1 = document.getElementById('select1')
  , sel2 = document.getElementById('select2');
  var os = select2data[sel1.value]; // Get the options required by select1.
  if (os) {
    sel2.options.length = 0; // Clear the options for select2.
    for (var i=0; i<os.length; i++) {
      var o = new Option(os[i][0], os[i][1]);
      try { // Add each option, allowing for browser differences.
        sel2.add(o);
      } catch (ex) {
        sel2.add(o, null);
      }
    }
    sel2.selectedIndex = 0;

  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this works as well (jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/RwxWx/

```
var select2data = {

  'English': [['One', 1], ['Two', 2], ['Three', 3]],
  'Spanish': [['Uno', 1], ['Dos', 2], ['Tres', 3]]
};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select1").bind("change", function() {
          sel2 = $("#select2").get(0);
          var os = select2data[this.value];
          if (os) {
                sel2.options.length = 0; // Clear the options for select2.
                for (var i=0; i<os.length; i++) {
                  var o = new Option(os[i][0], os[i][1]);
                  try {
                     // Add each option, allowing for browser differences.
                     sel2.add(o);
                  }
                  catch (ex) {
                     sel2.add(o, null);
                  }
               }
               sel2.selectedIndex = 0;
          }
          return true;
        });
    });

</script>


<select id="select1">
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Cybernate.

`sel1.onchange = function() {...}`
This means you attach the event to the element, but not excute it.